Mongo Spark Connector: Pagination using skip limit not working
I am trying to ingest data from mongodb into databricks using mongo spark connector. To paginate I am using skip, limit mongo aggregations. However, it returns the entire data no matter what I pass in the aggregation pipeline. I even passed random text in the aggregation pipeline, but it did not throw any error and instead returned all the records from mongodb in the dataframe. Please help.
micro_batch_size = 100000
skip_count = 4
while True:
    mongo_pipeline = [
        {
            "$sort": { "_id": 1 }
        },
        {
            "$limit": micro_batch_size
        },
        {
            "$skip": skip_count * micro_batch_size
        },

    ]

    temp_df = spark.read \
    .format("mongodb") \
        .option("spark.mongodb.connection.uri", mongo_conn_url) \
        .option("spark.mongodb.database", database) \
        .option("spark.mongodb.collection", collection) \
        .option("pipeline", mongo_pipeline) \
    .load()

I tried using "aggregation.pipeline" and "pipeline" options both but neither of them worked. When I try the same pipeline directly in mongodb, it works perfectly fine.
